'X-Frame-Options: DENY' Error During SSO Authentication in an iFrame
Currently, we're in the process of integrating Single Sign-On (SSO) functionality into our React/Typescript based iframe web application, which operates within an iframe.
For user authentication, we're utilizing Azure AD B2C, while AWS Cognito serves as our internal database for user data management. During development, within the iframe environment, we successfully implemented SSO login without any issues. However, upon deployment of our iframe application into the parent web application, we encountered an obstacle when trying to initiate the SSO login process.
Specifically, we received the error message:
"Refused to display 'https://test.b2clogin.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'."
Upon investigation, it became apparent that the 'X-Frame-Options' header for 'https://test.b2clogin.com/' is configured to 'deny', thereby preventing its display within iframes. Are there any potential solutions or workarounds for this issue?
We got stucked in the issue for some day, and can't find any potential fixes
Thanks for your help in Advance!
Tried changing the following:

X-Frame-Options in the AWS Cloudfront Distribution.

Allowed Access-Control-Allow-origin to *

AllowedHeaders to *

AllowedMethods to "PUT","POST","DELETE","GET".


But not found the way that is working.

Embedding the B2C authentication experience is only available with custom policies.
To enable the use of B2C in an iFrame add the following code to your custom policy relying party XML file(s)
<!--
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" /> -->
  <UserJourneyBehaviors> 
    <JourneyFraming Enabled="true" Sources="https://somesite.com https://anothersite.com" /> 
  </UserJourneyBehaviors>
<!--
</RelyingParty> -->

You can read more about how to implement this on the Microsoft Learn website.
This feature is not available for out-of-box user flows.

Please do not forget to "Accept the answer” and “up-vote” wherever the information provided helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.
